# SObject.addError() method does not prevent DML Operation

Tags: apex, database

I want to prevent DML operations during certain processing-situations and provoke a Database.SaveResult with an Database.Error[]-List.

According to [SObject class documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm?search_text=SObject%20class), the method `addError()` should "prevent any DML operation from occurring". As it turns out, this is not true. The following code commits the record to the database without any errors.

```java
Account a = new Account(Name = 'Valid Corp Name Ltd.');
a.addError('Error one');
a.addError('Error two');
Database.SaveResult sr = Database.insert(a, false);
System.debug(sr.isSuccess());
System.debug(sr.getErrors());
```

Debug log:

```
16:11:01:548 USER_DEBUG [5]|DEBUG|true
16:11:01:548 USER_DEBUG [6]|DEBUG|()
```

How can I prevent a record from beeing commited? I am aware of the similar question [sObject.addError did not prevent dml operation](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/82322/sobject-adderror-did-not-prevent-dml-operation), which did not get answered. So I am trying again.

Comment: r u using above code inside trigger or just anonymous/Method Block? i think  `addError` need to used against in Trigger operations

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Does addError() work outside of triggers?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/262376/2995)

Comment: yes, it can be considered a duplicate. I was not aware, that `addError` actually only works in trigger context, therefore I assumed the question was different.

Answer (score 4):

From the documentation
addError(errorMsg)
Marks a trigger record with a custom error message and prevents any DML operation from occurring.

So you can only this method in trigger context. In your example, `a` is just a variable and is not part of trigger context (i.e. trigger.new).

if you would do something like `trigger.new[0].addError('Some error')`, then changes to `trigger.new[0]` won't be commited.

Hope, it helps.

**Edit**:
In the referenced question, there is an answer. It just wasn't accepted for some reason (https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/82421/16508).

Comment: Thank you for clarification. Was not aware that this only works in trigger context.

Answer (score 1):

Copying my answer from [Does addError() work outside of triggers?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/262376/2995) as this is basically the same question.

---

It only works *on trigger context records*, but it can be applied to those records outside of a trigger. You cannot call this method on a record which is not yet in a trigger context, then have the error carry through to the trigger context.

This code won't prevent DML:

```
Account record = new Account();
record.addError('You cannot insert this record');
insert record;
```

However, this code will:

```
trigger Account on Account (before insert)
{
    PreventDml.validate(trigger.new);
}
public with sharing class PreventDml
{
    public void validate(List<SObject> records)
    {
        for (SObject record : records)
        {
            record.addError('You cannot insert this record');
        }
    }
}
```

If you are trying to test this code, the only realistic, effective way to make sure it does what you want is to run the trigger.  For example, in this scenario I might have a test like:

```
@IsTest
class AccountTriggerTests
{
    @IsTest static void testPreventDml()
    {
        DmlException expectedException;
        Test.startTest();
            try
            {
                insert new Account();
            }
            catch (DmlException dmx)
            {
                expectedException = dmx;
            }
        Test.stopTest();

        system.assertNotEquals(null, expectedException,
            'You should not be able to insert any Account');
        system.assertEquals(0, [SELECT count() FROM Account],
            'The database should be unchanged');
    }
}
```

Comment: close as duplicate?

Comment: Still trying to decide. I think for now I'll just post that as a comment and let the community vote.